# How to set members of mocked object

Tags: mockito

I remember reading an example which shows how to set member of a mocked object, for ex:

```
 MyClass mockedClass = mock(MyClass.class);

//and something like this to set `someVariable` with some value 
Mokito.set(mockedClass.someVariable, actual_value_intended_to_be_set);
```

Unfortunately I am not able to find that link again. Can someone give a reverence to
such examples or explain it here ?

Comment: I fear that you did not understand the concept of mocking. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your mock's outward behavior to look like mockedClass.someVariable has actual_value_intended_to_be_set, you can write:

```
when(mockedClass.getSomeVariable()).thenReturn(actual_value_intended_to_be_set);
```

Happy mocking!

Answer (score 0):

Is 'this' perhaps what you are looking for?

```
public class MyClassTest {

    @InjectMocks private MyClass mockedClass;

    @BeforeMethod(groups = { "unit" })
    public void setup() throws Exception {

        mockedClass = new MyClass();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(getSomeVariable()).thenReturn(actual_value_intended_to_be_set);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "unit" })
    public void testMyClass() throws Exception {
        //almost too trivial an example since you just setup this.
        Assert.assertEquals(getSomeVariable(), actual_value_intended_to_be_set);
    }

}
```

It creates your `MyClass` object and `sets` the return value as well.